# Play audio and video in same player android

Tags: android, media, android-mediaplayer

I have mp3 audio and mp4 video file, I want to play this in single player without creating two media player instance in android

Comment: please show code to show that you've tried SOMETHING

Comment: I was searching, which is the best way to do this ?

Comment: use https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/ vitamio library for vedios. its open source

Comment: Its not open source it has GPL and LPGL linsence